# unable to add gradient to TextFormField in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am trying to add gradient color to my TextFormField but unable to do since i am not sure how to do it.

below is my code so far

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Simple Interest Calculator'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column (
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
              child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: textInputType,
        style: Theme
              .of(context)
              .textTheme
              .title,
        controller: textController,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
           labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 16.0
           ),
           contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
             errorStyle: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.red,
             fontSize: 15.0
           ),
           enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
             borderSide:  BorderSide(color: colorTextInput, width:1.0),
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
           )
         )
    )
            ),


      ),
    );
  }
```

i am looking to have a gradient similar to the picture below.  instead of gradient going from top to bottom or bottom to top.  i am looking for gradient left to right.  i want to start with color "#fafafa" in left side and end with color "#EDEDED" in the right side of the textfield.  can someone help me on how to do that in flutter? thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    // below is custom color class
    class HexColor extends Color {
      static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
        hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
        if (hexColor.length == 6) {
          hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
        }
        return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
      }

      HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
    }

    class SharedColor {
      Color brightBlue = HexColor("cfe3e5");
    }

    // below is the container widget you need to add decoration in your text field container and you asked from left to right gradient change.

  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Simple Interest Calculator'),
      ),
      body: Form(

          child: Column (
              children: [

      Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      // Box decoration takes a gradient
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        // Where the linear gradient begins and ends
                        begin: Alignment.topRight,
                        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        // Add one stop for each color. Stops should increase from 0 to 1
                        stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
                        colors: [
                          // Colors are easy thanks to Flutter's Colors class.
                          SharedColor().brightBlue.withAlpha(800),
                          SharedColor().brightBlue.withAlpha(500),
                          SharedColor().brightBlue.withAlpha(400),
                          SharedColor().brightBlue.withAlpha(100),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
          child: TextFormField(
              style: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .title,
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 16.0
                  ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                  errorStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 15.0
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width:1.0),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
                  )
              )
          )
      ),
])));
```

Comment: change the gradient values and alignment for left to right acheivement you are looking

Answer (score 0):

I believe a fine solution or example is on this new library

gradient_textfield

It uses Container on top of TextField and inside TextField colours are transparent. It's a quick and efficient way of achieving linear-gradient on textField, though it will require extra customisation if you want to display different colours, borders in different states.

All rights & kudos to the lib author -> https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_textfield/install

```
class Gradienttextfield extends StatefulWidget {
  Gradienttextfield(
      {Key? key,
      required this.height,
      required this.width,
      required this.colors,
      required this.text,
      this.radius,
     required this.controller,
      this.fontColor,
      this.fontWeight,
      this.fontSize})
      : super(key: key);

  double? height;
  double? width;
  List<Color> colors;
  String? text;
  double? radius;
  TextEditingController? controller;
  Color? fontColor;
  FontWeight? fontWeight;
  double? fontSize;

  @override
  _GradienttextfieldState createState() => _GradienttextfieldState();
}

class _GradienttextfieldState extends State<Gradienttextfield> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20),
      child: Container(
        height: widget.height,
        width: widget.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: widget.colors,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.radius ?? 20.0)),
        child: TextField(
          controller: widget.controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.text,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: widget.fontColor ?? Colors.black,
                  fontSize: widget.fontSize ?? 18,
                  fontWeight: widget.fontWeight ?? FontWeight.bold),
              enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```